# zxing : forFragment Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: zxing

How to fix this?

IntentIntegrator test = new IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this);

forFragment, forforSupportFragment too

Cannot resolve symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your invocation is wrong. Should be

`IntentIntegrator test = new IntentIntegrator().forFragment(this);`

Notice the first parentheses.

or

`IntentIntegrator test = IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this);`

Sorry but I used the older version, so I am not sure how the invocation looks right now.

Comment: IntentIntegrator test = new IntentIntegrator().forFragment(this);            
This invocation has an error too. Not enough android skill yet. Help me